# Angular errorHandler vs window.onError global error handling

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli-v6

What are the differences between Angular ErrorHandler and window.onerror method?

Answer (score 0):

`window.onerror` does not work in Angular. You should use the following apis:

Angular provides a common method to handle Error. What you should do is to create a class implements ErrorHandler:

```js
import { ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';

export class AppGlobalErrorhandler implements ErrorHandler {
  handleError(error) {
   console.warn("customize catch execption:"+error);
  }
}
```

Then, in `app.module.ts`, you tell Angular to use our Custom Error Handler, configing in providers:

```js
providers: [
  // ...
  {
    provide: ErrorHandler,
    useClass: AppGlobalErrorhandler
  }
]
```

Reference：https://golb.hplar.ch/2018/10/global-errorhandler-angular.html